# Ruby - Manipulate CSV data, insert into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, csv

I'm using a rake task requiring Ruby's CSV class to import rows of property data, and would like to manipulate this data before inserting it into the database.

**CSV**

```
PID,City,Address,Sold Date,Sold Price
100-200-300,Vancouver,510 1700 Nelson Street,01/01/2017,"$500,000 "
200-300-400,Vancouver,304 68 Smithe Street,02/02/2017,"600,000"
```

**Residence Table (shortened for brevity)**

```
+-----+------+------+---------------+-------------+
| pid | city | unit | street_number | street_name |
+-----+------+------+---------------+-------------+
|     |      |      |               |             |
+-----+------+------+---------------+-------------+
```

**Rake Task (what I have so far)**

```
require 'csv'

desc 'Upload CSV data into database'
task residences: :environment do
  residences = Array.new
  counter    = 0
  csv_file   = "#{Rails.root}/public/spreadsheets/unformatted-addresses.csv"

  CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: :all, skip_blanks: true, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |row|

    #is this the right place to create the hash?
    residences << row.to_hash

    #is this the right way to format each cell?
    residences[counter][:pid]
    residences[counter][:city].downcase
    residences[counter][:address].downcase.split(" ")
    residences[counter][:sold_date]
    residences[counter][:sold_price].delete('$ ,').to_i

    Residence.create( #what to put here? )

    counter += 1
  end

  puts "Imported #{counter} rows."
end
```

What I would like to achieve is to individually format the cell contents then insert into appropriate columns, for example the address format should be:

**"Unit", "Street Number", "Street Name"**

Would greatly appreciate any help with this!

Comment: I see what you want to achieve, but what is your concrete question/issue? I don't even see what model do you plan to use for this

Comment: Assuming the Residence model has the fields you describe, you could do something like this Residence.create(:unit => unit, :street_number => street_number, :street_name => street_name), replace the unit, street_name, street_number with your actual data

Comment: Thank you Anton and Pierre, I've updated the question to hopefully be more explicit. Relatively new to the language so pardon the vagueness, but looking mostly for the correct sequence: Iterate over rows > Format cells > Split address into parts > Insert record into database.

Comment: Tip: Instead of `Array.new` just do `[ ]`. The long-form version is for special-case situations where you need to pass arguments to `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding onto my previous answer, you should be able to do something like this:

```
require 'csv'

address_regex = /(^\d+[a-z]?)+\s+(\d+)+\s+(.*)/i

desc 'Upload CSV data into database'
task residences: :environment do
  counter    = 0
  csv_file   = "#{Rails.root}/public/spreadsheets/unformatted-addresses.csv"

  CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: :all, skip_blanks: true, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |row|

    address = address_regex.match(row[:address])

    Residence.create(
      pid:           row[:pid],
      city:          row[:city],
      unit:          address[1],
      street_number: address[2],
      street_name:   address[3]
    )

    counter += 1
  end

  puts "Imported #{counter} rows."
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @DivXZero, definitely getting closer to what I want to achieve. I'm getting the following error: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: It was the header_converters: :symbol that messed me up. Should be row[:pid].

Answer (score 1):

The final result is below.

```
require 'csv'
require 'time'

namespace :csv do
  desc 'Upload CSV data into database'
  task residences: :environment do
    residences    = []
    counter       = 0
    csv_file      = "#{Rails.root}/public/spreadsheets/unformatted-addresses.csv"
    address_regex = /^(\d+[a-z]?)+\s+(\d+)+\s+(.+(?=\W))+\s+(.*)/i


    CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: :all, skip_blanks: true, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |row|
        address       = address_regex.match(row[:address])
        unit          = address[1]
        street_number = address[2]
        street_name   = address[3]
        street_type   = address[4]
        pid           = row[:pid].strip
        city          = row[:city].strip.downcase
        date          = Date.parse(row[:sold_date])
        sold_date     = date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
        sold_price    = row[:sold_price].strip.delete('$ ,').to_i

        puts "#{address}, #{pid}, #{city}, #{sold_date}, #{sold_price}"

        Residence.create(
          pid:           pid,
          city:          city,
          unit:          unit,
          street_number: street_number,
          street_name:   street_name,
          street_type:   street_type,
          sold_date:     sold_date,
          sold_price:    sold_price
        )

        counter += 1
    end

    puts "Imported #{counter} rows."
  end
end
```

Comment: You may see issues using the split method, as street names will differ, for example, '20 304 New York Street' is going to return 'York' as the street_type. You can use this updated regex and that will provide you with the street type using address[4] like my other examples: `/^(\d+[a-z]?)+\s+(\d+)+\s+(.+(?=\W))+\s+(.*)/i`

Comment: Just in case you want to understand what it's doing, you can check out how I built it here, click 'Explain', or 'Details' at the bottom :) http://regexr.com/3h7e6

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you're trying to do, assuming that every address is going to have a unit (it will also include any units with a character such as '12A':

```
address_regex = /(^\d+[a-z]?)+\s+(\d+)+\s+(.*)/i

matches = address_regex.match(residences[counter][:address])

unit          = matches[1]
street_number = matches[2]
street_name   = matches[3]
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/VEKh9cIe)

Note this isn't the most efficient code, I'm just aiming for clarity